# Including blog post title in URL for search engine optimization (SEO)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic, seo

Let me describe my situation first:
I have a blog website, where the blog entries are stored in a MySQL database and then loaded when the user accesses the website. Each blog post has tags that can be used to search the blog posts. I want users to be able to get my individual blog posts as results when they use a search engine like Google to search relevant words in the tags or title of the post.
 
For example, if I have a post with the title, "Including blog post title in URL for search engine optimization?", and a user searches something like "blog post title in url seo", then I would expect that my post should show up as one of the results (like when you search for programming questions on Google, a lot of the results come from Stackoverflow).
 I'm guessing I have to implement a system where I create a dynamic php page called post.php where this same page is used to display individual blog posts with the title of the post included in the url. Also it would be nice to have the post tags be included as meta keywords of this page. But I don't want to have a static page of each blog post on my server just so I can include the title in the url. If you look at the way stackoverflow does it, they have individual posts linking to urls where the title of the post is included in the url itself. I would like to have something similar. So my final reworded questions are:

1) **Is including post titles in URL good for SEO?**
2) **Is using dynamic pages that load blog post data from MySQL bad for SEO because the data isn't physically present on the website?**
3) **How do I create a dynamic page that is used to display individual blog posts when they are clicked and has the blog post title in the URL (similar to what Stackoverflow does)?** BONUS: if it can have the post tags as meta keywords that would be super awesome!

Comment: [TL;DR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read). Please break large explanations up into easily digestible chunks. Can you read this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **robots.txt** to link to **sitemap**, where you list all your urls. Google will find it.

Also, but not vital: use **.htaccess** to magically turn php-url-crap to domain.ext/category/post-id.html or any other **SEO friendly URL**.

Update:
Well, I don't trust in XML in general. All my sitemaps are php generated html files and they work just fine.

1. URL structure is important to SEO.
2. That doesn't matter. Look
   at Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal... same principle.
3. You have some page.php file that, before delivering html, does **SQL Query** and
   selects only data for that URL, then inserts it in html and each
   user, typing different urls, will see different content.

I suggest you spend some time watching or reading tutorials on subject "PHP MYSQL beginner CMS"

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-importance-of-sitemaps.html

Comment: Thanks, I think you guys pointed me in the right direction. As for sitemaps.xml (mentioned in the link you provided), would I just use php to append a new entry every time I write a new post (instead of just editing it manually)?

Comment: @hesson - You could do that by using [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Ask another question if you need some help doing that.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend reading tutorials. They are all old and use `mysql_*` functions (which are deprecated, by the way), as opposed to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['id']) && empty(trim($_GET['id']))) die('No post number specified!');
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'blog_db') or die('MySQL connection failed!');
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['id'])
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('MySQL query failed!');
$post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die('Fetching content failed!');
$title = $post['title'];
$content = $post['content'];
$tags = explode(',', $post['tags']);
$author = $post['author'];
$time = $post['time'];
?>
-->
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title><?php echo htmlentities($title); ?> &mdash; By Blog</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo implode(',', htmlentities($tags)); ?>" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="post">
        <div id="post-content">
<?php echo htmlentities($post); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="post-tags">
            <ul id="tags">
<?php foreach($tags as $tag) { ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="/tagged/<?php echo urlencode($tag); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($tag) ?></a>
                </li>
<?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="author">posted by <a href="/author/<?php echo urlencode($author); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($author); ?></a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You will probably want to look into URL rewriting (look at the URL of this: the title is visible, but an actual file does not exist), that will make it more search-engine friendly.

Also, having a sitemap for your visitors is good, because search engines will also follow links there.